# Compare an Arraylist and give output

Tags: java, arraylist

I have two ArrayLists.  How can I compare the elements in the arraylists and create a new list with the results?

I need to iterate through the list to actually get its results and compare.  How can I do it in Java?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Which language is this?

Comment: What results are you expecting, what are you comparing?

Comment: Java Language. I am comparing the status of devices and want to return that.So it is String values.

Comment: if you can give me a sample code, I can try to create something similar to it.

Comment: Do you want to compare to see if they are equal.... or something else....?

Comment: This site isn't a code delivery service or tutorial provider.

Comment: Ya compare and see if they are equal like Registered,UnRegistered etc as the devices in both the list are same.

Comment: Takendarrk-I am trying to get some inputs from others.Pls don't comment unnecessarily if you are not ready to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can compare by implementing `Comparator` class.You can understand by below example in which Two Time class is getting compared.

```
class Time
{
    int hours,minutes,seconds;
    public Time(int hours,int minutes,int seconds)
    {
        this.hours=hours;
        this.minutes=minutes;
        this.seconds=seconds;
    }
    public int getHours()
    {
        return this.hours;
    }
    public int getMinutes()
    {
        return this.minutes;
    }
    public int getSeconds()
    {
        return this.seconds;
    }
    public String toString()
    {
        return String.format("%d:%02d:%02d %s",((hours==0||hours==12)?   12:hours%12),this.minutes,this.seconds,((hours>=12)?"PM":"AM"));
    }  
}
class TimeComparator implements Comparator<Time>
{
    public int compare(Time t1,Time t2)
    {
        int hours=t1.getHours()-t2.getHours();
        int minutes=t1.getMinutes()-t2.getMinutes();
        int seconds=t1.getSeconds()-t2.getSeconds();
        if(hours>0)
        return 1;
        else if(hours<0)
        return -1;
        if(minutes>0)
        return 1;
        else if(minutes<0)
        return -1;
        if(seconds>0)
        return 1;
        else if(seconds<0)
        return -1;
        return 0;
    }
    public boolean equals(Object obj)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

After this you can use Collections class to use any method like sorting or search.

Comment: thanks Devavrat. Can I also use comparator class for ArrayList.

Comment: Yes you can use for any class from collections

Answer (score 0):

I hope that the following chunck of code will get you started.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

class Compare {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<String> a = new ArrayList<String>();
    a.add("Hello");
    a.add("Goodbye");
    ArrayList<String> b = new ArrayList<String>();
    b.add("Hello");
    b.add("Bye");

    if (a.size() != b.size()) {
      System.out.println("Arrays must have the same size");
      return;
    }

    ArrayList<Boolean> results = new ArrayList<Boolean>();
    for(int i = 0; i < a.size(); ++i)
      results.add(a.get(i).equals(b.get(i)));

    for(int i = 0; i < a.size(); ++i)
      System.out.println(results.get(i));
  }
}
```